# How to find Coefficient in product of binomials?

Tags: generating-functions

How can i find coefficient of $x^{51}$ in expansion of      $$(x-1)(x^2-2)(x^3-3)\ldots (x^{10}-10)?$$ I tried all methods and formulae but couldn't find the right answer.

Comment: is the third term $(x^3-3)$?

Comment: Pari states -1, but you surely want to have a formula ...

Comment: ? f=prod(j=1,10,x^j-j);print(polcoeff(f,51))

Comment: What about finding all partitions of 51 with the numbers 1 to 10, only available once ? This would give the necessary terms.

Comment: Peter how did u get it???whats pari?

Comment: PARI is a computational tool. The comment commencing with ? is the input line.

Comment: @user115908 [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr)

Comment: The title is misleading (the answer to that question would be: compute the binomial coefficient); in fact this question has nothing to do with the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $1+2+\cdots+10=55$.

When you multiply out this polynomial, you will get a sum of terms; each term is the result of choosing either one term or the other from each binomial, and multiplying all of them together.

So, you get an $x^{51}$ by choosing $x^{m}$ terms whose exponents add up to $51$, and using the constant terms for the others.

Now, because $1+2+\cdots+10=55$, you can equivalently consider this as choosing to use constant terms in place of $x^m$'s where the $m$'s add up to $4$.  How many different ways can you choose a subset of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,10\}$ that add up to $4$?  (Not very many!)

Comment: But wht if asked x^39 or somewhat like that?

Comment: @user115908 Well, then it gets harder!  It is likely not a coincidence that you weren't asked that.  If the expression was of a nicer variety, you could use generating function methods; you could also take derivatives (probably using logarithmic differentiation) and use them to find the Taylor series for this function about $x=0$.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson. I also think that Taylor series is really the best for the more general problem.

Comment: Ohhh.that's a better idea...i'll try that.thank you

Comment: @user115908 It's possible, but also significantly more complicated!  You need to compute the $51$st derivative of that product at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer by Nicholas R. Peterson, you can perform the following operations: put $y=x^{-1}$, multiply each factor $x^d-d$ by$~y^d$ (giving $1-dy^d$) and now the term in the expansion of the product of degree $55-k$ in $x$ has become a term of degree $k$ in$~y$. So concretely you are asking for the coefficient of $y^4$ in the product $\prod_{d\geq1}(1-dy^d)$; this is easy to compute.

I have made the product infinite; this does not change the coefficients in degrees${}\leq10$ (so it still gives an answer to your question), because the infinite product is mathematically more interesting. Nevertheless, it does not seem *that* interesting; [OEIS knows nothing](http://oeis.org/search?q=1,-1,-2,-1,-1,5,1,13,4,2,-8,-61,-31,13,-156,21,11,223&sort=&language=english&go=Search) about its sequence of coefficients $1,-1,-2,-1,-1,5,1,13,4,2,-8,-61,-31,13,-156,21,11,223,\ldots$